# How to get the timezone of a server?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I need timezone specific conditions for a cron, and the server being Google AppEngine, I have no idea where the server will be.

What's the best way to get the timezone?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111056/get-tz-information-of-the-system-in-python

Comment: Also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908994/how-to-get-current-uk-time-in-google-app-engine/17909487#17909487

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the App Engine documentation, servers are always set to UTC: http://timezones.appspot.com/ Do you have any indication that this is not correct?

See this answer for more information on finding the timezone on linux systems: [How do I find the current system timezone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118582/how-do-i-find-the-current-system-timezone)