# GAE & JavaScript datetime sync

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

What's the best practice for syncing time between client and server?

I have this function for querying datastore:

```
@classmethod
def read( cls, language=None, user=None, filters=None, **q_options ):
  assert not isinstance( cls, BaseModel )
  assert issubclass( cls, BaseModel )

  query = cls.query( cls.language == language )
  if filters:
    for name, value in cls.attributes( filters, [] ).iteritems():
      if name == 'updated':
        query = query.filter( getattr(cls, name) >= value )
      else:
        query = query.filter( getattr( cls, name ) == value )
    # logging.info( query )
    # Query(kind='Page', filters=AND(
    #   FilterNode('language', '=', 'en'),
    #   FilterNode('updated', '>=', datetime.datetime(2014, 5, 7, 9, 12, 51, 142000))))
    return query.fetch()
  data = query.fetch( **q_options )
  return cls.sort( data )
```

When executed with ajax call:

```
{method: 'GET', url: '/something.json?updated=' + (new Date().getTime() / 1000)}
```

it should return items that are updated after the time provided in the call. (I'm using it to sync browser's localStorage with real data). Well, it wasn't working, but I figured out it's because of the time difference between server and client.

I'm in UTC/GMT +2 hours, CEST (Central European Summer Time) time zone (that is what javascript sends) and GAE dev_appserver works at GMT. Compensating for this:

```
updated=((new Date().getTime() - 1000*60*60*2) / 1000)
```

solves the issue, but hardcoding it isn't a solution for different timezones. So, few questions:

1) What's the time zone for real GAE servers? Is it the same as dev_appserver's?

2) Should I deal with the difference in client or server context (javascript or python)?

3) Anything else I should know? (:

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest to deal with timezones on the server side as much as possible, since you never know how reliable your consummer/client is at interpreting/converting dates. The client's notion of time is relative to where he is, whereas your server's time should be the reference.

Comment: `new Date().getTime()` return the unix timestamp and it should not depend on the timezone. But the client only return the correct time if its clock is correct, so I think you shouldn't depend on it.

Comment: Yea, I agree server should be the reference... I'll use `var timestamp = (data ? hasOwnProperty.call( data, 'updated' ) : false) ? data.updated : new Date().UTC();` content date, with fallback to UTC. Thanks falks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post describe a solution: [How to get current UK time in Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17908994/how-to-get-current-uk-time-in-google-app-engine)

Google App Engine is always in UTC, so you need a library like [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) to adjust your preferences.