# Datetime in Google Cloud SQL [GAE + Python]

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-sql

I am having some problems storing a datetime variable in my Google Cloud SQL database. Everytime I store it, it will save it in UTC format and I want it in CEST+0200 (Spain's time zone).

With this function in Python, I can get the time I want:

```
def spain_timezone():
    fecha_actual_utc = datetime.now(timezone('UTC'))

    # Convert to Spain local time
    now_spain = fecha_actual_utc.astimezone(timezone('Europe/Madrid'))
    logging.info('time is %s', now_spain.strftime(fmt))

    return now_spain
```

Is there a way to save it as Spain's time zone?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just convert the timezone to Spanish whenever you retrieve it instead?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean with that? I can recover the time I want, but the date saved in the database is storaged in UTC time zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) library to do this, i found in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909487/142904) a example, but is very simple to use

```
import pytz
import datetime

fecha_actual_Madrid = pytz.timezone('Europe/Madrid')    
logging.info('time is %s', datetime.datetime.now(fecha_actual_Madrid ))
```

Comment: Yes, I've seen that example and I've used that python library. Finally I could solve it setting the Django settings.py USE_TZ = False and use the function astimezone() and timezone('Europe/Madrid'). Thank you so much for the answer.